# Transform data in an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm retrieving a list of items from an Observable on my Angular service. Inside every item, I have an array with a list of subjects. For every subject, I need to make another call to get its details (e.g. name, description, etc.).

**Data structure:**

```
- post1
  - subjects: ['books', 'cars', 'movies']
```

With that list, I have the `id` from every subject but I need to return an observable containing all subjects belonging to that post (and their details).

**AppService.ts**

```
getPost(id: string): Observable<Post> {
    return Observable.of({id: id, subjects: ['books', 'cars', 'movies']});
}

getSubjects(id: string): Observable<Subject[]> {
    return this.getPost(id).pipe(
        map((post: Post) => post.subjects),
        mergeMap((subjects: string[]) => subjects.map((id: string) => this.getSubject(id))),
        switchMap(list => list),
    );
}

getSubject(id: string): Observable<Subject> {
    switch (id) {
        case 'books':
            return Observable.of({id: 'books', name: 'Books'});
        case 'cars':
            return Observable.of({id: 'cars', name: 'Cars'});
        case 'movies':
            return Observable.of({id: 'movies', name: 'Movies'});
    }
}
```

It returns a stream of objects but I'd like to return an array with all subjects.

**[[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgdvqw?file=app%2Fapp.service.ts)]**

Comment: What is the definition of `subjectService.get()`?

Comment: It's an `Observable<Subject>`. I've updated my question with a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgdvqw?file=app%2Fapp.service.ts).

Comment: @brians69 you need to check what type `subjectService.get(id)` is returning.

Comment: Thanks, Rich. Yeah, it's returning a streaming of objects instead of an array. Do you know how can I return an array with all subjects? [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kufncw?file=app/app.service.ts)

Comment: Are there are a predefined (and relatively small) set of subjects? If so, it may make sense to retrieve the full list of all subjects, then filer the list for a particular post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you confused `.map()` of [`Observables.map()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) and the `.map()` of [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

This particular line of code:

```
 mergeMap((subjects: string[]) => subjects.map((id: string) => this.getSubject(id)))
```

does not return an array of `Subjects`; instead, it returns an array of `Observables` because the `subject` argument inside the function is an array, not an `Observable`. Hence, that particular `.map()` will return an array of the retyrn type of `this.getSubject(id)`, which is an array of `Observables`; exactly the behaviour you are getting.

If you want to have all the `Observables` resolved into an array of `Subjects`, you will have to use [`Observable.forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html). `.forkJoin()` combines all the observables and fire them in parallel.

```
getSubjects(id: string): Observable<Subject[]> {
    return this.getPost(id).pipe(
        map((post: Post) => post.subjects),
        mergeMap((subjects: string[]) => Observable.forkJoin([...subjects.map((id: string) => this.getSubject(id))])),
    );
}
```

Now you can use it in your component:

```
getSubjects(id).subscribe(values=>{
    console.log(values)//returns an array of Subjects
})
```

Note that `Observables.forkJoin` will have to wait for **all** observables to complete before firing an emission.