# Populate data in an Observable based on data in the Observable itself

Tags: angular, typescript

First off: I'm new to Angular so the terms here might be wrong. I hope I can get the understanding through.

I'm consuming an API. Endpoint A exposes `Ticket`s; these `Ticket`s hold an array (0-*) of `Attachment`s. Those `Attachment`s are not complete; in the data model they contain the base64 string of the content of the underlying file but to reduce general load the `Attachment`s are only complete when fetched from Endpoint B. But in order to fetch an `Attachment` from Endpoint B I need the `Attachment`'s `id` which I can only get from Endpoint A.

What I need to happen is that I fetch `attachment.id` from Endpoint A, use that id to fetch the approriate `Attachment` from Endpoint B, and replace `Attachment`s in the result from Endpoint A with the result from Endpoint B. However since the `Attachment`s are retreived as `Observable` I can't just simply assign the value.

The following snippet is one of several attempts at solving this and is able to get the `Attachment`s from the API but they aren't assigned the way I wanted.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(`getting ticket for id ${this.id}`);
  this.ticket$ = this.ticketService.getTicket(this.id).pipe(
    map((response:Ticket) => {
      response.attachments.map((attachmentPartly:Attachment) => {
        console.log(`getting attachment for id ${attachmentPartly.id}`);
        let attachmentFilled = this.ticketService.getAttachment(attachmentPartly.id);
        attachmentFilled.subscribe(att => console.log(`base64 content is: ${att.base64Content}`)); //for posterity: this line has been omitted in tests with no change in result
        return attachmentFilled;
      });
      return response;
    })
  );
}
```

`getTicket` returns an `Observable<Ticket>`. `getAttachment` returns an `Observable<Attachment>`.

As can be seen I've started to debug by logging (since the angular app is hosted within a larger system that also provides authorization against the endpoints I can't really debug it the right way...) and the base64 value is written to the console, so at least some parts of the code works as I want. For instance for a text/plain type file I can get the value "SGV5IHRoZXJlLCByYW5kb20gcGVyc29uIGZyb20gU3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw" written to the console which matches the value found when I execute the query manually via Postman.

I suspect that I'm trying to assign an `Observable` (`attachmentFilled`) to the `Attachment[]` but TS is not warning about illegal type conversions. Looking at the Network tab in Chrome DevTools I can't see the call to `getAttachments` only the calls to `getTickets`.
The data models for `Ticket` and `Attachment` are:

```
export interface Ticket {
    id?:               string;
    description?:      string;
    assignee?:         string;
    createdAt?:        string;
    resolvedAt?:       string;
    attachments?:      Attachment[];
}

export interface Attachment {
    name?:          string; //contained in result from Endpoint A
    id?:            string; //contained in result from Endpoint A
    relatesTo?:     string; 
    type?:          string; //contained in result from Endpoint A
    sizeBytes?:     string; //contained in result from Endpoint A
    hash?:          string;
    url?:           string;
    base64Content?: string; //need to fetch this
}
```

I'm using the following template to create the download file links (hugely inspired by [angular-file-saver download base64 file using FileSaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352396/angular-file-saver-download-base64-file-using-filesaver)):

```
<div *ngFor="let attachment of ticket.attachments" class="list-group-item">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
        <a [href]="'data:' + attachment.type + ';base64,' + attachment.base64Content | safeUrl" target="_blank" download="{{ attachment.name }}">{{ attachment.name }}</a>
        <small>{{ attachment.sizeBytes | filesize }}</small>
    </div>
    <small class="mb-1">{{ attachment.type }}</small>
</div>
```

which results in the following html (notice how only the data from Endpoint A is populated):

```
<div _ngcontent-dmp-c28="" class="list-group-item">
    <div _ngcontent-dmp-c28="" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
        <a _ngcontent-dmp-c28="" target="_blank" download="test.txt" href="data:text/plain;base64,undefined">test.txt</a>
        <small _ngcontent-dmp-c28="">43 B</small>
    </div>
    <small _ngcontent-dmp-c28="" class="mb-1">text/plain</small>
</div>
```

(Url sanitization, inspired by [Angular2 Base64 sanitizing unsafe URL value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141534/angular2-base64-sanitizing-unsafe-url-value), appear to force the null base64content to `undefined`. Before santitization there would be nothing where there now is `undefined`).

The `getAttachment` endpoint only accept the `attachment.id` as an input.

I have tried to implement the solution in [Transform data in an Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553022/transform-data-in-an-observable) this way:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(`getting ticket for id ${this.id}`);
    this.ticket$ = this.ticketService.getTicket(this.id).pipe(
    mergeMap((response: Ticket) => forkJoin([...response.attachments.map((attachment : Attachment) => this.ticketService.getAttachment(attachment.id))])));
}
```

But to no awail: `this.ticket$` throws an error "Type 'Observable<Attachment[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Type 'Attachment[]' has no properties in common with type 'Ticket'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is a classical problem asked very often here.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.ticket$ = this.ticketService.getTicket(this.id).pipe(
    switchMap((response: Ticket) => {
      const filledAttechments$ = response.attachments.map(
        (attachmentPartly: Attachment) => this.ticketService.getAttachment(attachmentPartly.id).pipe(
          map(att => ({ ...attachmentPartly, base64Content: att.base64Content })),
        ),
      );

      return forkJoin(filledAttechments$).pipe(
        map(filledAttachments => ({...response, attachments: filledAttachments})),
      );
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: If it is asked very often I must be so off in my nomenclature that I couldn't find it. Thank you for answering it yet again - it worked the first time without any issues. There's some interesting syntax going on there, what does "{ ..." do? (A link to documentation is enough).

Comment: There is no common word to find the other issues I mean. It's just my experience that many questions come down to this solution. ... is the spread operator. It includes all properties of the spread object. Into the new object started  with {